# preg_replace taking out an extra string

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a preg_replace taking out a part of a string it shouldn't be removing.
It should be looking for: images_client/39/structure/party-2/
And replacing it with: images_client/39/structure/xxx/
It does do that, but it's also removing the images/  part of it just before apple_logo.jpg

```
 <?php 
    echo '<br>-------- preg_replace on a css string with slashes ------<br>';
    $string='/images_client/39/structure/party-2/images/apple_logo.jpg';
    echo 'Before: '.$string.'<br>';
    print preg_replace("/images_client\/39\/structure\/(\S+)\//", "images_client/39/structure/xxx/", $string) . "\n";
?>
```

Comment: Please, when dealing with patterns containing forward slashes, choose a different pattern separator (you can pick whatever you want): all those `\/` make eyes bleed. Also you might consider accepting some answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_replace('#images_client/39/structure/[^/]+/#s', 'images_client/39/structure/xxx/');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `[^/]` instead of `\S`:

```
/images_client\/39\/structure\/([^\/]+)\//
```